# Set focus on textfield when un-focused

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I want a text field to always be focused. When they click out of the textfield, I want the focus to go back into the textfield.

How would I accomplish this with jQuery?

```
$('input').focus();

$('input').**unfocused?**( function($) { $('input').focus();} );
```

Comment: jQuery event handlers do not take a `$` parameter.  (They take an event object)

Comment: Have you considered the usability implications of making an "always focused" text field? I don't know about you, but text boxes grabbing focus is one of my personal pet hates on the internet (especially when you're part way through filling out a form and focus jumps mid-typing)

Comment: Yes I have. There is only one field on the entire page and that is the user's only focus

Comment: i'm wondering what will happen if you have two textfields with this kind of setup and you un-focus one of them to focus on the other. Will they be like fighting for the focus back and forth? :P

Comment: This is very user-hostile (especially if the user depends on a screen reader).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code is an alternative solution which depends on periodically checking the control's state.

```
var controlFocus=false;
$("#txtName").focus(function(){
    $(this).addClass("focused"); 
    if(!controlFocus) {
        controlFocus = true;
        setInterval(function(){ 
            var o = $("#txtName");
            if(!o.hasClass("focused")) o.focus();
        }), 200);
    }
}).blur(function(){$(this).removeClass("focused");});
```

After the textbox (named txtName) gets its first focus, every 0.2 second, the code controls whether the textbox has focus. If it doesn't, it's focused. But this can be a really annoying thing.

Comment: I understand the idea but the script gives me errors. Also, wont this build up and make the site really slow?

Comment: What's the error? In fact I tried it on Jsfiddle with Chrome. You can increment the interval to 500 or 1000.

Comment: From error console: Error: missing ; before statement
Source Code:
        }), 200);

Answer (score 3):

You're looking for the [`blur` event](http://api.jquery.com/blur/):

```
$(':text').blur(function() { this.focus(); });
```

Comment: `$("input").blur(function(){
    $("input").focus();
  });` does not work

Answer (score 0):

Bind to get the change event, and check if focus must be forced to this input if so, insert some data in the document. $(document).data(‘_force_focus’, e.target)

```
$('input.force').bind('change', function(e) {
        if( need_force_focus() ) {
                $(document).data('_force_focus', e.target);
        } else {
                $(document).removeData('_force_focus');
        }
   });
```

Now on the document bind to the focusin event, testing if document have the “_force_focus” data. If so set the focus to the value. It’s important prevent the focusin retrigger by testing against e.target

```
$(document).bind('focusin', function (e) {
     var t = $.data(document, '_force_focus');
             if( t && e.target !== t ) {
                     $(t).trigger('focus');
                     return false;
             }
             return true;
     });
```